# How to read the next character after space in C?

Tags: c, scanf, space

I have to write a program which input is:

**Spring Miles Indie Lie Ego**

and the result will be:
*SMILE*

But I have some problems with the input. I don't know the length of the input, so it can be any length.

That's why I use scanf to read every single character. I count the spaces to know the size of the array where I'm going to save the characters I need.

So after these here is my main problem:
If I found a space I should save the next character which I read from scanf, but how can I do that?
Or do you guys know any other option to solve this problem?

Here's my code so far:

```
int main()
{

    char ch;
    int i = 0, count= 0;

    while(scanf("%c", &ch) != EOF)
    {
        if(ch == '\n')
            count = 0;

        if(ch == ' ')
            count++;

        char array[count+1];

        if(ch == ' ')
         array[i++] = ch + 1; // I tried this, but it doesn't work.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have to read the next character. since you already know how to read a character.... I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: You must move the `array` declaration out of the loop.  The way you have it, it will be created as an array with zero elements on the first iteration unless the character is a space.

Comment: I got it but if I declare out of the loop how will I know the size?

Because i don't know how long the line will be. That's why I use the counter to declare the perfect size for the array to save the first characters after every space.

Comment: In two steps if necessary.  You can loop through the text, count spaces, and set array size accordingly.  But in this case, since you know everything about what the array needs to contain, you could even create it as `char array[6];` the extra element to make room for NULL terminator.

Comment: Just saying an alternate way of writing your program is just to filter to keep the capital letters.  Then you don't need to worry about position related to white space

Comment: I think the OP is implying that they don't know what the input will be ahead of time.  As well, the input is coming from stdin, and you can't reparse that, unless you store the string somewhere in the first place (and again, what size array do you use...).   They would need dynamic memory allocation for this...  I'll post a quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define char array in the while loop, the array will never be available.If the while loop run 10 times, your code will define 10 char array but on one is available after the while loop done.Bellow is my code

```
int main() {
    char ch;
    char array[1024];
    int i = 0, count= 0;
    int status = 1;
    while(scanf("%c", &ch) != EOF) {
        if(ch == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        if(ch == ' ') {
            status = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (status == 1) {
            status = 0;
            array[i++] = ch;
        }
     }
     array[i++] = ' ';
     printf("%s", array);
     return 0;
}
```

My code is based on the assumption that the array length will not more length than 1024.We can not know the length of input before others input something.So malloc maybe helps you.
Malloc is a function in C.You can use it to manage your main memory.

Comment: 1) Did you want `array[i++] = '\0';`? 2) `while(i < 1023 && scanf("%c", &ch) != EOF) {` prevents a code exploitation.

Comment: Why do you add a space to the array after the loop?

Answer (score 1):

`ch` is a `char`. It doesn't make sense here to add the number `1` to the character "space". Instead, you have to read the next character from the string. You can do it like that:

```
int main()
{

    char ch;
    bool had_space;
    int i = 0, count= 0;

    had_space = true;

    while(scanf("%c", &ch) != EOF)
    {
        if(ch == '\n')
            count = 0;

        if(ch == ' ')
            count++;

        char array[count+1];

        if(ch == ' ')
            had_space = true;
        else if (had_space)
            array[i++] = ch;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I guess you also have to define the array outside of the loop.

Comment: *You can't add the number 1 to the character "space"* - of course you can.

Comment: And what is the result of this operation? Edit: Well, ok, I guess you'd get the next ASCII-character. I should have written "It doesn't make sense" - I'll change that.

Comment: @Pharaoh It makes perfect sense and you explained it in your comment. The ASCII chart is deterministic.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense if that is what you need - but you don't get the next character of the string you have read the character from, which what that question is about. It does not make sense the way Kyntha has done it.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is truly unknown to start with, and you don't know how many spaces it will contain, you need dynamic memory allocation -- this means you allocate memory as you need it rather than trying to stick it in a fixed size piece of memory on the stack.  There are a couple ways about this, but I think that simple linked lists are the cleanest.   The following should do what you need:

```
typedef struct linkedListNode {
     char                ch;
     struct linkedList * next;
} linkedListNode_t;

linkedListNode_t *pHead = NULL;
linkedListNode_t **ppNext = &pHead; 

// pHead points to the first node in the list
// ppNext points to the pointer to the next element in the list


while(scanf("%c", &ch) != EOF) {
    if (ch == ' ') {
        // scan next character, and add to linked list:
        if (scanf("%c", &ch) == EOF)
             break;   // exit loop if we've hit end of input
        // ch is ok -- add to list:
        // allocate a new pNode to store the information
        linkedListNode_t *pNode = malloc(sizeof(linkedListNode_t);
        if (pNode == NULL) {
             printf("Out of memory -- aborting");
             exit (-1);  // if allocation failed, abort program
        }
        pNode->ch = ch;
        pNode->next = NULL;
        *ppNext = pNode;        // make previous node point to this one.
        ppNext = &pNode->next;  // update ppNext
    }
    else if (ch == '\n') {
        // special handling of newline -- did you want to print the
        // string and dump memory here?        
    }
} // end wile loop

// at this point we have a linked list with all characters that 
// follow spaces -- print it out:
linkedListNode *pNode = pHead;

while (pNode != NULL) {
    printf("%c", pNode->ch);
    pNode = pNode->next;
}
printf("\n");      

// free list:
pNode = pHead;
linkedListNode *pNext;
while (pNode) {
    pNext = pNode->pNext;
    free(pNode);
    pNode = pNext;
}
```

disclaimer: I haven't tested the above, so it's possible I made a syntax error.  In any case, you look to be somewhat new to C, so I would strongly suggest drawing this out to make sure you understand how it works.